# Changes needed in INI file using getini-content

Tags: powershell, ini

regarding `Getini-content` module.
i have tried using it,

1. but after saving the file using this command
   ' "$File | Out-IniFile -Force "C:\MyiniFile.ini"'
   all the space lines between [KEY] are gone and the file massed up.
2. i didnt find a way to change all the lines texts under [KeyName] from this

   [fruits]

   apples = red

   banana = yellow

to something like this

```
;[fruits]
;apples = red
;banana = yellow
```

moreover i didnt find much more of examples online. even not here.

ill be happy to learn more about this module.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- The third-party [`PsIni`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni/) module you're using:

  - does *not* support preserving empty lines when reading and later rewriting an `.ini` file with `Out-IniFile`

    - However, you can pass `-Pretty` so as to separate sections with an empty line.
  - *does* support commenting out *individual settings*, but not *section* lines.

```
# Create a sample .ini file.
@'
[sec1]
val1=1
val2=3
[sec2]
val3=4
val4=5
'@ > test.ini

# Read the file.
$settings = Get-IniContent test.ini

# Comment out all settings in section [sec2],
# and write the result back to the file with -Pretty
$settings | 
  Add-IniComment -Section sec2 -Keys $settings['sec2'].Keys |
  Out-IniFile -Pretty -Force test.ini
```

Thereafter, `test.ini` contains the following; note the empty line between the sections and that all keys in `[sec2]` are commented out (but not the section name itself):

```
[sec1]
val1=1
val2=3

[sec2]
;val3=4
;val4=5
```